# How do I create a textbox using vba and call it for other action later on

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'd like to select 3 shapeboxe:, slide title, sub slide title and source text. For the 2nd and 3rd selected text I will create a new textbox and copy and paste over the text. (The reason I create this is there are some textboxes in my presentation that simply do not respond to my VBA code and only copy and paste them to a new table, then I can follow up with formatting.)

I step through using F8 till the code stops at the 3rd selection - it then cannot continue. I was thinking it could be when the 2nd textbox is created, my selection of 3rd textbox wasn't considered a selection anymore. I want to find a way to create a textbox, name it and then be able to call it for action later on.

```
Dim sld As slide, sh As Shape, cursh As Shape, cursh2 As Shape

Set sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
'Do something

Set cursh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2)
cursh.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=500, Height:=50) 

sh.textFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
sh.Line.Visible = msoFalse 

cursh.Delete 

Set cursh2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(3)
cursh.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=500, Height:=50) 

sh.textFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
sh.Line.Visible = msoFalse 

cursh.Delete
```

My complete code is as follows. Hope to know what's wrong and also see if anyone could offer any better way to simplify my code.

```
Sub Select_SlideTitle_Only2()

'Note: Set sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)(To use for selecting active shape

Dim sld As slide, sh As Shape, cursh As Shape, cursh2 As Shape
Dim Tbl As Table, myRow As Long, myCol As Long
Dim myWidthST As Long, myHeightST As Long, myTopST As Long, myLeftST As Long, myFontST As String, myCNFontST As String, myFontsizeST As Long, myFontcolorST As String, _
myMarginST As Long, myShapenameST As String, myVerticalAlignmentST As String, myBulletST As String, myBoldST As String, myAlignmentST As String

'Define for Message
Dim myWidthMT As Long, myHeightMT As Long, myTopMT As Long, myLeftMT As Long, myFontMT As String, myCNFontMT As String, myFontsizeMT As Long, myFontcolorMT As String, _
myMarginMT As Long, myShapenameMT As String, myVerticalAlignmentMT As String, myBulletMT As String, myBoldMT As String, myAlignmentMT As String
'Select textbox, place them on itx designated location and name it "Messagebox" with margin as zero

'Define for source formatting
Dim myWidthS As Long, myHeightS As Long, myTopS As Long, myLeftS As Long, myFontS As String, myCNFontS As String, myFontsizeS As Long, myFontcolorS As String, _
myMarginS As Long, myShapenameS As String, myVerticalAlignmentS As String, myBulletS As String, myBoldS As String, myAlignmentS As String


'Select textbox and turn the textbox to Frutiger 55 Roman formatting with margin all around as zero

myFontST = "Frutiger 45 Light"
myFontsizeST = 28
myWidthST = 723.6
myHeightST = 74.16
myTopST = 0.0002362005
myLeftST = 33.12
myMarginST = 0
myShapenameST = "PAGE HEADING"
myVerticalAlignmentST = msoAnchorBottom

Dim x As Long
x = InputBox("Please enter a number for format. 1 = Title only, 2 = Title + Message, 3 = Title + Message + Source(Left Btm, 4 = Slide title + Message + Source(Center bottom)", "Gerald Slide Title Formatting")

Select Case x

Case Is = 1

Set sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

        With sh
        .Width = myWidthST
        .Height = myHeightST
        .Top = myTopST
        .Left = myLeftST
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Name = myShapenameST
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .Bullet = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFontST
        .Size = myFontsizeST
        .Bold = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMarginST
        .MarginRight = myMarginST
        .MarginBottom = myMarginST
        .MarginTop = myMarginST
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignmentST
        End With

Case Is = 2

'Slide Title
myFontST = "Frutiger 45 Light"
myFontsizeST = 28
myWidthST = 723.6
myHeightST = 74.16
myTopST = 0.0002362005
myLeftST = 33.12
myMarginST = 0
myShapenameST = "PAGE HEADING"
myVerticalAlignmentST = msoAnchorBottom

Set sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

        With sh
        .Width = myWidthST
        .Height = myHeightST
        .Top = myTopST
        .Left = myLeftST
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Name = myShapenameST
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .Bullet = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFontST
        .Size = myFontsizeST
        .Bold = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMarginST
        .MarginRight = myMarginST
        .MarginBottom = myMarginST
        .MarginTop = myMarginST
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignmentST
        End With

'Message Text

myFontMT = "UBSHeadline"
myFontsizeMT = 14
myFontcolorMT = RGB(70, 71, 73)
myWidthMT = 723.6
myHeightMT = 21.6
myTopMT = 85.5
myLeftMT = 33.12
myBoldMT = msoFalse
myMarginMT = 0
myShapenameMT = "MESSAGE TEXT"
myVerticalAlignmentMT = msoAnchorTop

Set cursh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2)
cursh.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=50) 'this shape will now be called sh

sh.textFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
sh.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

cursh.Delete 'Delete the selected shape

        With sh
        .Width = myWidthMT
        .Height = myHeightMT
        .Top = myTopMT
        .Left = myLeftMT
        .Name = myShapenameMT
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .Bullet = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFontMT
        .Size = myFontsizeMT
        .Bold = myBoldMT
        .Color.RGB = myFontcolorMT
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMarginMT
        .MarginRight = myMarginMT
        .MarginBottom = myMarginMT
        .MarginTop = myMarginMT
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignmentMT
        End With




Case Is = 3

'Slide Title

myFontST = "Frutiger 45 Light"
myFontsizeST = 28
myWidthST = 723.6
myHeightST = 74.16
myTopST = 0.0002362005
myLeftST = 33.12
myMarginST = 0
myShapenameST = "PAGE HEADING"
myVerticalAlignmentST = msoAnchorBottom

Set sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

        With sh
        .Width = myWidthST
        .Height = myHeightST
        .Top = myTopST
        .Left = myLeftST
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Name = myShapenameST
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .Bullet = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFontST
        .Size = myFontsizeST
        .Bold = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMarginST
        .MarginRight = myMarginST
        .MarginBottom = myMarginST
        .MarginTop = myMarginST
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignmentST
        End With

'Message Text

myFontMT = "UBSHeadline"
myFontsizeMT = 14
myFontcolorMT = RGB(70, 71, 73)
myWidthMT = 723.6
myHeightMT = 21.6
myTopMT = 85.5
myLeftMT = 33.12
myBoldMT = msoFalse
myMarginMT = 0
myShapenameMT = "MESSAGE TEXT"
myVerticalAlignmentMT = msoAnchorTop

Set cursh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2)
cursh.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=50) 'this shape will now be called sh

sh.textFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
sh.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border



        With sh
        .Width = myWidthMT
        .Height = myHeightMT
        .Top = myTopMT
        .Left = myLeftMT
        .Name = myShapenameMT
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .Bullet = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFontMT
        .Size = myFontsizeMT
        .Bold = myBoldMT
        .Color.RGB = myFontcolorMT
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMarginMT
        .MarginRight = myMarginMT
        .MarginBottom = myMarginMT
        .MarginTop = myMarginMT
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignmentMT
        End With

'Source Left full

myFontsizeS = 8
myWidthS = 723.6
myHeightS = 15.12
myTopS = 505.38
myLeftS = 33.12
myMarginS = 0
myAlignmentS = ppAlignLeft
myBulletS = msoFalse
myVerticalAlignmentS = msoAnchorBottom
myShapenameS = "SourceText"
myFontcolorS = RGB(0, 0, 0)

Set cursh2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(3)
cursh2.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=50) 'this shape will now be called sh

sh.textFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
sh.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

cursh2.Delete 'Delete the selected shape

        With sh
        .Width = myWidth
        .Height = myHeight
        .Top = myTop
        .Left = myLeft
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Name = myShapename
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = myAlignment
        .Bullet = myBullet
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFont
        .Size = myFontsize
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .Color.RGB = myFontcolor
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMargin: .MarginRight = myMargin: .MarginBottom = myMargin: .MarginTop = myMargin
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignment
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.Ruler
        .TabStops.Add ppTabStopLeft, 30
        .TabStops.Add ppTabStopLeft, 13
        End With

Case Is = 4

myFontST = "Frutiger 45 Light"
myFontsizeST = 28
myWidthST = 723.6
myHeightST = 74.16
myTopST = 0.0002362005
myLeftST = 33.12
myMarginST = 0
myShapenameST = "PAGE HEADING"
myVerticalAlignmentST = msoAnchorBottom

Set sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

        With sh
        .Width = myWidthST
        .Height = myHeightST
        .Top = myTopST
        .Left = myLeftST
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Name = myShapenameST
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .Bullet = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFontST
        .Size = myFontsizeST
        .Bold = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMarginST
        .MarginRight = myMarginST
        .MarginBottom = myMarginST
        .MarginTop = myMarginST
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignmentST
        End With

'Message Text

myFontMT = "UBSHeadline"
myFontsizeMT = 14
myFontcolorMT = RGB(70, 71, 73)
myWidthMT = 723.6
myHeightMT = 21.6
myTopMT = 85.5
myLeftMT = 33.12
myBoldMT = msoFalse
myMarginMT = 0
myShapenameMT = "MESSAGE TEXT"
myVerticalAlignmentMT = msoAnchorTop

Set cursh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2)
cursh.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=50) 'this shape will now be called sh

sh.textFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
sh.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

cursh.Delete 'Delete the selected shape

        With sh
        .Width = myWidthMT
        .Height = myHeightMT
        .Top = myTopMT
        .Left = myLeftMT
        .Name = myShapenameMT
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .Bullet = msoFalse
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFontMT
        .Size = myFontsizeMT
        .Bold = myBoldMT
        .Color.RGB = myFontcolorMT
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMarginMT
        .MarginRight = myMarginMT
        .MarginBottom = myMarginMT
        .MarginTop = myMarginMT
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignmentMT
        End With


'Source Bottom center full

myFontsizeS = 8
myFontcolorS = RGB(0, 0, 0)
myWidthS = 617.47
myHeightS = 19.17
myTopS = 551.9857
myLeftS = 125.0239
myMarginS = 0
myAlignmentS = ppAlignLeft

myBulletS = msoFalse
myVerticalAlignmentS = msoAnchorMiddle
myShapenameS = "SourceText"
myFontcolorS = RGB(0, 0, 0)

Set cursh2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(3)
cursh2.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=50) 'this shape will now be called sh

sh.textFrame.TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteText
sh.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

cursh2.Delete 'Delete the selected shape

        With sh
        .Width = myWidth
        .Height = myHeight
        .Top = myTop
        .Left = myLeft
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Name = myShapename
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = myAlignment
        .Bullet = myBullet
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.TextRange.Font
        .Name = myFont
        .Size = myFontsize
        .Color.RGB = myFontcolor
        End With

        With sh.textFrame
        .MarginLeft = myMargin: .MarginRight = myMargin: .MarginBottom = myMargin: .MarginTop = myMargin
        .VerticalAnchor = myVerticalAlignment
        End With

        With sh.textFrame.Ruler
        .TabStops.Add ppTabStopLeft, 30
        .TabStops.Add ppTabStopLeft, 13
        End With

Case Else
MsgBox ("You have not selected any shape, please try again")

End Select



End Sub
```

Comment: The `Shape` object has a `Name` property, which you do use. You can work with a Shape at any time using that property: `Shapes(shName)` or `ShapeRange(shName)`. If you want to re-use the Shape in the same code, declare a variable for each different Shape: `Dim sh1 as Shape, sh2 as Shape, sh3 as Shape` and set them to different Shapes. Then just use the variable as required. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks Cindy, but not exactly what I want. I want to be able to name the shape after I created with VBA as following... hope this clarify
Set cursh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2)
cursh.textFrame.TextRange.Copy

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=500, Height:=50)